# Difficulty interpretting correlation between two data frames

Tags: r, correlation

I have two data frames, from which I'm attempting to determine whether a correlation exists.  The basic question I'm attempting to ask is whether winter weather patterns lead to a spike in births (nine months later).

The data frames have been simplified to contain only (what I presume is) the necessary information.  The weather data frame contains only observations that line up with the birth data frame being nine months later.  When I use the ccf function, it's successfully plotting the data, but I know I'm not setting it up correctly.  I need to account for one variable (model.weather) happening nine months before the correlation is drawn with the other (model.births).

Right now, it's setup very simply:

```
ccf(model.weather$EVENT_TYPE, model.births$BIRTH_TOTAL)
```

**Can anybody help me to properly offset the data by nine months?**

Here is what the two data frames look like:

```
dput(model.weather)
structure(list(DATE = structure(c(13514, 13514, 13545, 13545, 
13545, 13545, 13545, 13545, 13545, 13545, 13545, 13545, 13545, 
13545, 13545, 13545, 13545, 13545, 13545, 13545, 13573, 13573, 
13573, 13573, 13573, 13573, 13573, 13573, 13573, 13573, 13573, 
13573, 13573, 13573, 13573, 13573, 13573, 13573, 13573, 13573, 
13573, 13573, 13604, 13604, 13604, 13848, 13848, 13848, 13848, 
13848, 13848, 13848, 13848, 13848, 13848, 13848, 13848, 13848, 
13848, 13848, 13848, 13848, 13848, 13848, 13848, 13848, 13848, 
13848, 13848, 13848, 13848, 13848, 13848, 13848, 13848, 13848, 
13848, 13848, 13848, 13848, 13848, 13848, 13848, 13848, 13848, 
13848, 13848, 13848, 13848, 13848, 13848, 13848, 13848, 13879, 
13879, 13879, 13879, 13879, 13879, 13879, 13879, 13879, 13879, 
13879, 13879, 13879, 13879, 13879, 13879, 13879, 13879, 13879, 
13879, 13879, 13879, 13910, 13910, 13910, 13910, 13910, 13910, 
13910, 13910, 13910, 13910, 13910, 13910, 13910, 13910, 13910, 
13910, 13910, 13910, 13910, 13910, 13910, 13910, 13910, 13939, 
13939, 13939, 13939, 13939, 13939, 13939, 14214, 14214, 14214, 
14214, 14214, 14214, 14214, 14214, 14214, 14214, 14214, 14214, 
14214, 14214, 14214, 14214, 14214, 14214, 14214, 14214, 14214, 
14214, 14214, 14214, 14214, 14214, 14214, 14214, 14214, 14214, 
14214, 14214, 14214, 14214, 14214, 14214, 14214, 14214, 14214, 
14214, 14214, 14214, 14214, 14214, 14214, 14214, 14214, 14214, 
14214, 14214, 14214, 14214, 14214, 14214, 14214, 14214, 14214, 
14214, 14214, 14245, 14245, 14245, 14245, 14245, 14245, 14245, 
14245, 14245, 14245, 14245, 14245, 14245, 14245, 14245, 14245, 
14245, 14245, 14245, 14245, 14245, 14245, 14245, 14245, 14245, 
14245, 14245, 14245, 14245, 14276, 14276, 14276, 14276, 14304, 
14304, 14304, 14304, 14304, 14304, 14304, 14304, 14304, 14304, 
14304, 14304, 14304, 14304, 14304, 14304, 14304, 14304, 14304, 
14304, 14304, 14579, 14579, 14579, 14579, 14579, 14579, 14579, 
14579, 14579, 14579, 14579, 14579, 14579, 14579, 14579, 14579, 
14579, 14579, 14579, 14579, 14579, 14579, 14579, 14579, 14579, 
14579, 14579, 14579, 14610, 14610, 14610, 14641, 14641, 14641, 
14641, 14641, 14641, 14641, 14641, 14641, 14641, 14641, 14641, 
14641, 14641, 14641, 14641, 14641, 14641, 14641, 14641, 14641, 
14641, 14641, 14641, 14641, 14944, 14944, 14944, 14944, 14944, 
14944, 14944, 14944, 14944, 14944, 14944, 14944, 14944, 14944, 
14944, 14944, 14944, 14944, 14944, 14944, 14944, 14944, 14944, 
14944, 14975, 14975, 14975, 14975, 14975, 14975, 14975, 14975, 
14975, 14975, 14975, 14975, 14975, 14975, 14975, 14975, 14975, 
14975, 14975, 14975, 14975, 14975, 14975, 14975, 14975, 14975, 
14975, 14975, 14975, 14975, 14975, 14975, 14975, 14975, 14975, 
14975, 14975, 14975, 14975, 14975, 14975, 14975, 14975, 14975, 
14975, 14975, 14975, 14975, 14975, 14975, 14975, 14975, 14975, 
14975, 14975, 14975, 14975, 14975, 14975, 14975, 14975, 14975, 
14975, 14975, 14975, 15006, 15006, 15006, 15006, 15006, 15006, 
15006, 15006, 15006, 15006, 15006, 15006, 15006, 15006, 15006, 
15006, 15006, 15006, 15006, 15006, 15006, 15006, 15006, 15034
), class = "Date"), EVENT_TYPE = structure(c(5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 
5L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 8L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("Hail", "Heavy Snow", 
"Winter Storm", "Winter Weather", "Ice Storm", "Frost/Freeze", 
"WINTER WEATHER", "Blizzard"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("DATE", 
"EVENT_TYPE"), row.names = c(1475L, 1476L, 1477L, 1478L, 1479L, 
1480L, 1481L, 1482L, 1483L, 1484L, 1485L, 1486L, 1487L, 1488L, 
1489L, 1490L, 1491L, 1492L, 1493L, 1494L, 1495L, 1496L, 1497L, 
1498L, 1499L, 1500L, 1501L, 1502L, 1503L, 1504L, 1505L, 1506L, 
1507L, 1508L, 1509L, 1510L, 1511L, 1512L, 1513L, 1514L, 1515L, 
1516L, 1519L, 1520L, 1521L, 1588L, 1589L, 1590L, 1591L, 1592L, 
1593L, 1594L, 1595L, 1596L, 1597L, 1598L, 1599L, 1600L, 1601L, 
1602L, 1603L, 1604L, 1605L, 1606L, 1608L, 1609L, 1610L, 1611L, 
1612L, 1613L, 1614L, 1615L, 1616L, 1617L, 1618L, 1619L, 1620L, 
1621L, 1622L, 1623L, 1624L, 1625L, 1626L, 1627L, 1628L, 1629L, 
1630L, 1631L, 1632L, 1633L, 1634L, 1635L, 1636L, 1638L, 1642L, 
1643L, 1644L, 1645L, 1646L, 1647L, 1648L, 1649L, 1650L, 1651L, 
1652L, 1653L, 1654L, 1655L, 1656L, 1657L, 1658L, 1659L, 1660L, 
1661L, 1662L, 1665L, 1666L, 1671L, 1672L, 1673L, 1674L, 1679L, 
1680L, 1681L, 1682L, 1683L, 1684L, 1685L, 1686L, 1687L, 1688L, 
1689L, 1690L, 1691L, 1692L, 1693L, 1694L, 1696L, 1697L, 1698L, 
1699L, 1700L, 1701L, 1702L, 1703L, 1863L, 1864L, 1865L, 1866L, 
1867L, 1868L, 1869L, 1870L, 1871L, 1872L, 1873L, 1874L, 1877L, 
1878L, 1879L, 1880L, 1881L, 1882L, 1883L, 1884L, 1885L, 1886L, 
1887L, 1888L, 1889L, 1890L, 1891L, 1892L, 1893L, 1894L, 1895L, 
1896L, 1897L, 1898L, 1899L, 1900L, 1901L, 1902L, 1903L, 1904L, 
1905L, 1906L, 1907L, 1910L, 1911L, 1916L, 1917L, 1918L, 1919L, 
1920L, 1921L, 1922L, 1923L, 1924L, 1925L, 1926L, 1927L, 1928L, 
1929L, 1933L, 1934L, 1935L, 1938L, 1940L, 1941L, 1942L, 1943L, 
1944L, 1945L, 1946L, 1947L, 1948L, 1950L, 1951L, 1952L, 1953L, 
1955L, 1956L, 1957L, 1958L, 1959L, 1960L, 1961L, 1962L, 1964L, 
1965L, 1966L, 1967L, 1968L, 1969L, 1974L, 1976L, 1977L, 1978L, 
1979L, 1980L, 1981L, 1982L, 1983L, 1984L, 1985L, 1986L, 1987L, 
1988L, 1989L, 1990L, 1991L, 1992L, 1993L, 1994L, 1995L, 1996L, 
1998L, 2071L, 2072L, 2073L, 2074L, 2075L, 2076L, 2077L, 2078L, 
2079L, 2080L, 2081L, 2082L, 2083L, 2084L, 2085L, 2086L, 2087L, 
2088L, 2089L, 2090L, 2091L, 2092L, 2093L, 2094L, 2095L, 2096L, 
2097L, 2098L, 2105L, 2106L, 2107L, 2108L, 2109L, 2110L, 2111L, 
2112L, 2113L, 2114L, 2115L, 2116L, 2117L, 2118L, 2119L, 2122L, 
2123L, 2124L, 2125L, 2126L, 2127L, 2128L, 2129L, 2130L, 2131L, 
2132L, 2133L, 2134L, 2184L, 2185L, 2186L, 2187L, 2189L, 2190L, 
2191L, 2192L, 2193L, 2194L, 2195L, 2196L, 2197L, 2198L, 2199L, 
2200L, 2201L, 2202L, 2203L, 2204L, 2205L, 2206L, 2207L, 2208L, 
2209L, 2212L, 2213L, 2214L, 2215L, 2216L, 2217L, 2218L, 2219L, 
2220L, 2221L, 2222L, 2223L, 2224L, 2225L, 2226L, 2227L, 2228L, 
2229L, 2230L, 2231L, 2232L, 2233L, 2234L, 2235L, 2236L, 2237L, 
2238L, 2239L, 2240L, 2241L, 2242L, 2243L, 2244L, 2245L, 2246L, 
2247L, 2248L, 2249L, 2250L, 2251L, 2252L, 2253L, 2254L, 2255L, 
2256L, 2257L, 2258L, 2259L, 2260L, 2261L, 2262L, 2263L, 2264L, 
2265L, 2266L, 2267L, 2268L, 2269L, 2270L, 2271L, 2272L, 2273L, 
2274L, 2275L, 2276L, 2277L, 2278L, 2279L, 2280L, 2281L, 2282L, 
2283L, 2284L, 2285L, 2286L, 2287L, 2288L, 2289L, 2290L, 2291L, 
2292L, 2293L, 2294L, 2295L, 2303L, 2304L, 2305L, 2308L), class = "data.frame")

dput(model.births)
structure(list(DATE = structure(c(13514, 13545, 13573, 13604, 
13634, 13665, 13695, 13726, 13757, 13787, 13818, 13848, 13879, 
13910, 13939, 13970, 14000, 14031, 14061, 14092, 14123, 14153, 
14184, 14214, 14245, 14276, 14304, 14335, 14365, 14396, 14426, 
14457, 14488, 14518, 14549, 14579, 14610, 14641, 14669, 14700, 
14730, 14761, 14791, 14822, 14853, 14883, 14914, 14944, 14975, 
15006, 15034, 15065, 15095, 15126, 15156, 15187, 15218, 15248, 
15279, 15309), class = "Date"), BIRTH_TOTAL = c(6250, 5833, 6570, 
6227, 6858, 6735, 6933, 7291, 6385, 6466, 6198, 6221, 6341, 6051, 
6444, 6396, 6781, 6583, 6820, 6803, 6531, 6510, 5627, 6135, 5976, 
5515, 6208, 6261, 6520, 6509, 6834, 6616, 6489, 6318, 5730, 6040, 
5667, 5459, 6162, 6212, 6221, 6194, 6469, 6380, 6342, 5981, 5853, 
5925, 5979, 5414, 6070, 6085, 6242, 6438, 6506, 6459, 6260, 6158, 
5754, 5801)), .Names = c("DATE", "BIRTH_TOTAL"), row.names = c(NA, 
-60L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Your whole methodology is wrong. lagging a data frame is easy, but while in "model.birth" your dates are unique, they aren't unique in the "model.weather" data.frame. Thus you are comparing different dates with the same date and etc.

Comment: @DavidArenburg: I had a feeling that would be the case.  model.births is five years/sixty months; would it make sense to total up the events in model.weather by month/year, to reflect the same sixty months, and then compare?  And if so, can you point to a reference on how to do that?

Comment: You can do two things here. First is to give same weight to each event ("heavy snow", "winter storm" and etc) and "pile them up" per unique date, or you can compare each event separately to lagged model.birth. I can illustrate them both in an answer if you like

Comment: @DavidArenburg: that would be *extremely* helpful.  I've been struggling with this for quite a while, and would very much appreciate any help you can offer.  Thank you for anything you can do to help.

Comment: The only problem I see is that you have lots of missing dates in "model.weather", so I hope it's not the case in your original data

Comment: There is a reason for that: there were no "extreme" winter events in those months (by my pre-established criteria).  For instance, there were no extreme winter events in April 2006, so there are no values.  Because there were no winter events in that month (and others), I wouldn't expect them to have any correlation on a "spike" in births nine months later, if that makes sense.  The goal is to determine whether these extreme winter events have any influence on spiking births nine months later, so I expect summer, spring, and fall months to have very little impact.

Comment: So maybe when there are no extreme events we should set the value to zero (instead of missing value) that would make more sense imo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So us we discussed in the comments, you have to compare "apples with apples", thus both data sets have to be compared by unique dates.

First approach will be to give same weight to each event, count them and compare to "model.births"

```
## Aggrgating "model.weather" by date and counting events
aggmodel.weather <- aggregate(EVENT_TYPE ~ DATE, data = model.weather, length)
## Merging to "model.births" by DATE
model.births <- merge(model.births, aggmodel.weather, by = "DATE", all.x = T)
## Setting the missing events to zero
model.births[is.na(model.births$EVENT_TYPE), "EVENT_TYPE"] <- 0
## Running `ccf` funciton, notice the documentation of `ccf` which states "The lag k value returned by ccf(x, y) estimates the correlation between x[t+k] and y[t]"
ccf(model.births$BIRTH_TOTAL, model.births$EVENT_TYPE)
```

[image]

The output is in conclusive imo. See [here](https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat510/?q=book/export/html/74) for further reading

Second approach is to compare each type of event in "model.weather" to "model.birth"

```
## Checking the event types
table(model.weather$EVENT_TYPE)
##     Hail     Heavy Snow   Winter Storm Winter Weather 
##        0            283            127              0 
##Ice Storm   Frost/Freeze WINTER WEATHER       Blizzard 
##       16              0              0              1 
## Lets try "Heavy Snow" as it seems the most frequent (doing everything as previously)
Heavy.Snow <- model.weather[model.weather$EVENT_TYPE == "Heavy Snow", ]
Heavy.Snow <- aggregate(EVENT_TYPE ~ DATE, data = Heavy.Snow, length)
model.births <- merge(model.births, Heavy.Snow, by = "DATE", all.x = T)
model.births[is.na(model.births$EVENT_TYPE.y), "EVENT_TYPE.y"] <- 0
ccf(model.births$BIRTH_TOTAL, model.births$EVENT_TYPE.y)
```

[image]

The output look pretty much the same. You can try that for some other "EVENT_TYPE"s too.

This code was for illustration purposes, for further analysis see the link above.

Last thing, if you want to lag the "model.births" data by 9 months you can simply do:

```
model.births$BIRTH_TOTAL2 <- c(model.births$BIRTH_TOTAL[10 : (length(model.births$BIRTH_TOTAL))], rep(NA, 9))
model.births <- model.births[complete.cases(model.births), ]
```

`"BIRTH_TOTAL2"` will be your lagged variable

Comment: Thank you very much, David.  I'm exploring these now, and will read through the link you posted.  This is hugely helpful so thank you again.